# What is the correct way to check if two dates overlap

Tags: apex, class, date, business-logic

I have 2 object. They both have a start date and an end date.
How can I check if they overlap?

now I have:

```
if((item1.DateStart__c >= item2.DateStart__c && item1.DateStart__c <= item2.DateEnd__c) ||
    (item1.DateEnd__c >= item2.DateStart__c && item1.DateEnd__c <= item2.DateEnd__c) ||
    (item1.DateStart__c <= item2.DateStart__c && item1.DateEnd__c >= item2.DateEnd__c)) {

    //error
}
```

This does not work...

Comment: What is the error??

Comment: If you mean the error I want to give, it's just an error to say that is overlapping.

Comment: Ahhh...my misunderstanding.  I thought you were saying you were receiving an error.  My mistake

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm not getting an error message, I'm trying to give one ! :)

Comment: So, is there a specific scenario its not working for??  It looks like it should work for certain scenarios.  Can you isolate which cases its not working for?

Comment: Found it, just a typo.  You are comparing a value to itself.  Added an answer to this effect

Answer (score 2):

Looks like its just a typo.  In your 3rd scenario, you are comparing `item1.DateEnd__c` to itself.  You just need to change it to `item2.DateEnd__c`

```
if((item1.DateStart__c >= item2.DateStart__c && item1.DateStart__c <= item2.DateEnd__c) ||
    (item1.DateEnd__c >= item2.DateStart__c && item1.DateEnd__c <= item2.DateEnd__c) ||
    (item1.DateStart__c <= item2.DateStart__c && item1.DateEnd__c >= item2.DateEnd__c)) {

    //error
}
```

Comment: Excuse me.. that would be a typo. My apologies.

Comment: No worries.  Happens to the best of us.  Always good to get another set of eyes on it.  Thats what we are here for :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend reading this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap

Overall, what you need to do is set up logic as below. This will always result in finding overlapping dates.

```
if(item1.DateStart__c <= item2.DateEnd__c && item1.DateEnd__c >= item2.DateStart__c){
    //error
}
```